# Assign a set of roles to a set of people

Tags: prolog

I am trying to write a program to solve [this game](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/67608/a-space-station-13-complicated-escape). You need not check it out for this question.

The thing is, there are 6 people:
Chaplain,ChiefEngineer,MedicalDoctor,Clown,Roboticist,SecurityOfficer

They share the following roles:
NukeOp,Facehugged,Cyborg,Changeling and 2 x Ok

My idea is to use facts in the form of role(person) eg
NukeOp(Chaplain).

The question is, how can I create a rule that says that when one person has a specific role, then

1. The same person has no other role; eg if NukeOp(Chaplain) then not Facehugged(Chaplain). (Note: I hope I won't meet the negate-by-cut monster again! Or should I create possible negation facts?)
2. The same role cannot be taken from others; eg if NukeOp(Chaplain) then not NukeOp(Clown). Exception: There are two Ok(X) guys, so there must be two values for X in Ok(X) before Ok(X: any other value than these two) should be calculated false

I'd like, if possible, an answer that leads me to the correct way of thinking without providing the entire solution thus taking the fun out of both modeling and remembering the language :)

Comment: If you're starting just knowing people and roles but not who has what role yet, then the uniqueness can be established dynamically. For example, if at some point in the code you think you want to assign a role to a person, you can query the role for the person first to see if you get a successful query. If it succeeds, then you do not want to assign another role.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be easier if you use predicates of the form `hasRole(Person, Role)`.

To ensure a person has only a single role:

```
hasSingleRole(Person, Role) :- hasRole(Person, Role), \+ ((hasRole(Person, Role2), Role \= Role2)).
```

Likewise, to ensure a role is unique:

```
hasUniqueRole(Person, Role) :- hasRole(Person, Role), \+ ((hasRole(Person2, Role), Person\= Person2)).
```

It is possible to do the same with the `role(Person)` format, but it requires you to explicitly list all roles and do some meta programming.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis that's how you write "not" in Prolog.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis In particular, it means that the expression that follows cannot be proven. Notice the double parentheses! Because of the `,` in the expression, if you have only one pair of parentheses Prolog will try to call `\+` with two arguments, which does not work

Comment: The amount of reading I need to do in order to understand this is larger than the comment size! Can you please provide a link, not to a generic tutorial page, but one that is associated with the specific tip?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis which tip? The double paren? I'm not sure if there is a particular source for this, it's just an artifact of the ambiguous syntax where `,` can mean both "logical and" and "next argument".

Comment: You know what I don't understand? If I provide some hasRole facts such that all persons are assigned a role, but person P1 exists with no role, and there is only role R1 remaining, will your rule create the hasRole(P1,R1) fact? It seems to me your rules are only meant to assert the 1-1 role-person parings, not create them. I need to create them, though.

Comment: Ok this goes beyond what I can explain in a comment, but basically there is a difference between imperative and logical programming. In logical programming, you dont "create facts", you reason upon the facts that are given. If you have a riddle where you want to find out which person has which role, you need to define the solution space (eg a list of person-role pairs) and then implement the facts that describe a valid solution.

Comment: OK, I am changing my statement from "does your rule create the hasRole(P1,R1) fact)?" to "does your rule make the knowledge base such that if I query hasRole(P1,R1) it will return true?". Having the base deduce correctly all possible hasRole(X,Y) answers to queries, is the solution.

Comment: No, that is the point. Rules do not add any knowledge to other rules, this is not how Prolog works.

Comment: OK, let me state it in as little terms of prolog if possible. Let's say there were only 2 persons, P1 and P2, and only two roles, R1 and R2. I provide the fact hasRole(P1,R1). Due to each person having exactly one role, I logically deduce that hasRole(P2,R2). I want prolog to do this for me. So, you must tell me the rules I should include so that if I query hasRole(P2,R2) it returns true. I don't think I am wrong up to this point, since this is just specification. Will your rules do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174023/discussion-between-cephalopod-and-george-menoutis).

Comment: "Due to each person having exactly one role" is a constraint you must inform Prolog of, it doesn't come with that kind of knowledge.